# LiquiBase usage for tests in Jhipster

Tags: jhipster, liquibase

I want to repopulate database after each test with LiquiBase in Jhipster app. How cat I set up Junit test to do it?

I see that Initially LiquiBase is run at application start up via:

```
@Bean
public SpringLiquibase liquibase(@Qualifier("taskExecutor") Executor executor,
        DataSource dataSource, LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties) {

    // Use liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase if you don't want Liquibase to start asynchronously
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
    liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml");
    liquibase.setContexts(liquibaseProperties.getContexts());
    liquibase.setDefaultSchema(liquibaseProperties.getDefaultSchema());
    liquibase.setDropFirst(liquibaseProperties.isDropFirst());
    liquibase.setChangeLogParameters(liquibaseProperties.getParameters());
    if (env.acceptsProfiles(Profiles.of(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_NO_LIQUIBASE))) {
        liquibase.setShouldRun(false);
    } else {
        liquibase.setShouldRun(liquibaseProperties.isEnabled());
        log.debug("Configuring Liquibase");
    }
    return liquibase;
}
```

but I cant find a way to drop all tables and rerun all change sets.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it enough to use `@Transactional` annotation on your tests?

Liquibase is mainly useful for building your schema and partially for loading some test data in JHipster but if your tests are transactional, data inserted or modified by your test will be rollbacked automatically after each test method.

Droping the schema and re-creating it for each test would much slower.
Even if you don't want to use a transactional test, it would be faster to delete table contents than droping tables and re-creating them.

Comment: `@Transactional` doesn't suit me in my case. Deleting all data and inserting it again is good, but still I don't see any way to do it with LiquiBase. Anyway thanks for pointing out that LiquiBase isn't right tool for my case.

Comment: You don't do it using Liquibase but using your own code. Have a look et https://brightinventions.pl/blog/clear-database-in-spring-boot-tests/